# character position of a multi-line selection within a content editable div using javascript

Tags: javascript

Please take a look at this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/darrengates/jwx41Lkz/

In this example, I have an editable div with 3 lines. I'm attempting to get the start character position, and end character position, of a selection.

This appears to work for the first line only. If I highlight more than 1 line, the values are incorrect (see the comments for an explanation).

How do I get the start and end character position of a selection when it spans multiple lines? (i.e., the character position starting at the first letter of the entire div, so for example the "s" in "second line" would be approximately character position 11).

Here's what I have so far (runnable in the fiddle):

```
<div id="test" contenteditable="true" class="selecttest">
first line<br />
second line<br />
third line
</div>
```

```
.selecttest {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```
function getSelection() {

    const sel = document.getSelection() || window.getSelection();

    // note: if I highlight the 2nd and 3rd lines
    // start and end values are 1, 11
    // they should be about 11 and 22 (or so)
    // on account of the existence of the first line
  
    let start = sel.baseOffset
    let end = sel.extentOffset
  
    // if selected from right to left, reverse...
    if ( start > end ) {
      const temp = start;
      start = end;
      end = temp;
    }
  
    console.log('start, end', start, end)
}

$("#test").on('mouseup', function() {
    getSelection();
})
```

It seems that there are many S.O. posts relating to getting selected text, but answers relating to getting the selected character positions all fail when selecting multiple lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to measure position in a range, you should be using a range object rather than the selection object.

A proposal on this code pen > https://codepen.io/aSH-uncover/pen/ExEdXwy

The main trick is to address the two scenarios where the range is inside the same container or not :)

```
function getSelection() {
  const sel = document.getSelection() || window.getSelection();

  const range = sel.getRangeAt(0)
  
  let rangeContainer = range.commonAncestorContainer
  let same = false
  if (rangeContainer === range.startContainer) {
    same = true
    rangeContainer = range.startContainer.parentElement
  }
  
  let start = -1
  let end = -1
  
  const list = rangeContainer.childNodes
  let offset = 0
  for (let i = 0 ; i < list.length ; i++) {
    const current = list[i]
    if (current === range.startContainer) {
      start = offset + range.startOffset
      if (same) {
        end = offset + range.endOffset
        break
      }
    } else if (current === range.endContainer) {
      end = offset + range.endOffset
      break
    }
    if (current.nodeName === '#text') {
      offset += current.length
    }
  }
  
  console.log('start, end', start, end)
}
```

Edit : if you want to support more complex text (like a div with spans) you will have to improve this function and include some recursive stuff :)